# How to check and toast when there is no response from server site in android?

Tags: android

I have to check the condition when there is no response from server back end as case like when i had connected my android phone to a WiFi,and shows network active in my android phone,
but the problem is when WiFi(router) is not connected to any internet service that time i need a toast.

How can i check and make a toast when i don't get any response from server back end ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this method to check whether connected to internet or not?

```
  public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                        && activeNetwork.isConnected();
                return isConnected;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Null check for response:

```
if(response == null){ 
Toast.makeText(context, "No Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}  else{
// parse response
}
```

Comment: This thing i had done already the basic think is that some time there is internet connect to other WiFi devices but that other devise dose not have any access to internet at that time when i pares or fetch any data from internet the connectivity is true but there will be no data pares so i need a toast

Comment: then use null check for response. If null then show toast.

Comment: Thanks like this if(response = null ) toast ?

Comment: thanks this is showing a warring error i had this - @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
       
      Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
      hidePDialog();
       if(response == null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       }
       else{}

Comment: Add@supperWaring 'unused' on onRespones

Comment: ok then just add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") above this code. It will be better for me if you write your whole code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62340/discussion-between-prince-and-hitesh-matnani).